# Show that $\frac{\alpha}{(k+1)^{1-\alpha}}\leq (k+1)^{\alpha}-(k)^{\alpha} \leq \frac{\alpha}{k^{1-\alpha}}$

Tags: inequality

Let $\alpha \in ]0,1[$. Show for every positive integer $k \geq 1$ we have
$$
\frac{\alpha}{(k+1)^{1-\alpha}}
\leq (k+1)^{\alpha}-(k)^{\alpha}
\leq \frac{\alpha}{k^{1-\alpha}}
$$
I need some hint for this. I was thinking  we consider the function $f(x)=(1+x)^{\alpha}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:** consider $f(x)=x^{\alpha}$ on the interval $[a,b]$ for some $0<a<b$. Then for every $x,y\in[a,b]$
$$
f(y)-f(x)=f'(\xi)(y-x)
$$
hold for some $\xi\in[a,b]$. In your case $x=a=k$ and $y=b=k+1$, so it is enough to find max and min of $f'$ on $[k,k+1]$.

Comment: OMG  I forgot Mean value theorem . Thank you

Comment: You are welcome

Answer (score 1):

*Another way*: Use Bernoulli inequality.

The right inequality is written as
$$\left(\frac{k+1}{k}\right)^\alpha - 1 \le \frac{\alpha}{k}.$$

The left inequality is written as
$$\frac{\alpha}{k + 1} \le 1 - \left(\frac{k}{k+1}\right)^\alpha.$$

Both inequalities are true by the Bernoulli inequality
$$(1 + x)^r \le 1 + rx, \quad \forall x > -1, \, 0 \le r \le 1.$$
Indeed, for the right inequality, let $x = \frac{1}{k}$ and $r = \alpha$, and for the left inequality, let $x = -\frac{1}{k + 1}$ and $r = \alpha$.